# Timeout error when calling API from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, https, node-modules

I am calling this public API from my nodejs. I am using system in office enviornment and I have to connect with VPN to accress office url. When I use wifi of my mobile then I can access below API.

```
https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees
```

the above is public API. anybody can check.

I have to use `https` to access API in node because of security reasons. How can i access the API when I am in my office enviornment. I am getting below error.

```
Error:connect ETIMEDOUT 52.220.246.189:443.
```

below is the code.

```
const https = require('https');
https.get('https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees', (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
        console.log(data);
    });

    resp.on('end', () => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation);
    });
    console.log("data");

}).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

How can I resolve the same?

Comment: Which http client package are you using, e.g. http, axios, request, needle, node-fetch etc?

Comment: If you connected to the VPN you are using, do you have access to other public site? if not, than the problem is with your VPN's DNS configurations or routing.

Comment: @yanivisrael ya I can connect all the public site including above restapi when I am accessing from browser. but when I am accessing from node it is giving timeout. if I disconnect VPN then even node can access.

Comment: @TerryLennox https